# discord.py send Message faster to multiple Channels

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am about to make a Global Chat bot and it works pretty good but since it is in 70 Servers, he really struggles with sending the Messages. At the moment my code to send the messages looks like this:

```
async def sendallchannel(self, embed):
for channel in fetchedchannel:
    try:
        await channel.send(embed = embed)
    except:
        pass
```

and as I just said, it take about 1 Minute till the Message is send to every Server. Is there a way to send the Messages faster?

the variable fetchedchannel is a list of every channel already fetched, so the Bot don't need to fetch every Channel one by one when he wants to send a Message

Comment: You are not providing a minimum reproducible example, since the fetchedchannel variable is not declared. You also have a typo with "mawait" instead of await.

Comment: the mawait was just a typo here in stackoverflow and the fetchedcahnnel variable is declared somewhere else, but thats just a list of the Channel so its not nessasary for the question, but I shuld have mentioned it sorry

Comment: Oh, ok, didn't know you already had the list of the channels. I'm going to edit my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be much faster as all coroutines will be ran concurrently :

```
async def sendallchannel(self, embed):
  coroutines = [channel.send(embed=embed) for channel in fetchedchannel]   
  await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)
```

Comment: i think if you use a generator, works faster: `(channel.send(embed=embed) for channel in fetchedchannel)`

Comment: I didn't think about coroutines, your answer is probably more useful for me than for the OP. +1

Comment: this works way better, but is there a way to do an Exception with this? so it looks something like `coroutines = [try: channel.send(embed=embed) exceot: pass for channel in fetchedchannel] `? I don't really know how you could do it, and I don't find anything on the Internet that really helps

Comment: @Kollhdxdlp this article is very well written on that topic : https://piccolo-orm.com/blog/exception-handling-in-asyncio/

Answer (score 0):

As I know, this is the fastest way:

```
@bot.command()
async def sendToAllChannels(ctx, *message):
    message = ' '.join(message)
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.send(message)
```

---

Notice that this way you are using a `nested` `for` loop, that obviously takes a lot of time, in particular when the outer loop (the one iterating over `bot.guilds`) is executed many times (you said `70`, right?)

---

Since you only want to send messages to `TextChannel`s, you can add this check:

```
if str(channel.type) == 'text':
```

---

EDIT: Since you already have a list of all the channels (`fetchedchannel`), assuming this list contains all the channels the `bot` can see, I would create a new list this way...

```
fetchedTextChannels = [channel for channel in fetchedchannel if str(channel.type) == 'text']
```

...in order to avoid the `try`/`except` block, once you know all the channel are of type `'text'`.

---

Then, in order to make the messages not to wait each other, you should see the solution by @[Loic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3322400/lo%C3%AFc) that suggests you to use `async`hronous coroutines, and will make everything much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the faster:

```py
def _send_in_all_channels(ctx, embed):  # outside cog
  channels = ctx.guild.text_channels  # type: list[TextChannel]

  coroutines = (channel.send(embed=embed) for channel in channels)
  # types.Genetrator[typing.Awaitable[discord.Message], None, None]

  return asyncio.gather(*coroutines)  # type: typing.Awaitable

# usage in cog
@commands.command('big-send')
async def big_send(self, ctx, message: str):
  await _send_in_all_channels(ctx, discord.Embed(discerption=message))
  await ctx.send('done')
```